# Asterisk AGI fails to execute cURL

Tags: curl, asterisk, agi

I'm using Bicom PBXware. I have complex cURL with headers to send using -H which means I can not use Asterisk CURL app. So I created bash script which works properly:

```html
/opt/pbxware/pw/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin # cat resp_example.sh 
#!/bin/bash

resp=`/usr/bin/curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Card: 512912***" -H "Exp: 1125" -H "user: somebody@gmail.com" -H "Username: ***" -H "Api_token: ***" -X POST https://somewebsite/apiivr/getbalance`

#resp='{"result":true,"balance":"4315.94","message":"ok"}'

echo "SET VARIABLE resp '---> $resp'"

echo "NoOp resp: $resp"
```

so this bash script works perfectly from Linux CLI, but fails from dialplan:

```
exten => 2006,1,AGI(resp_example.sh)
same => n,Hangup
```

I chmoded all to 777 but it still fails:

```html
    /opt/pbxware/pw/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin # ls -lah
    total 260K
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Sep  1 09:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 14  555  555 4.0K Sep  1 10:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  100 Aug 31 05:51 CC-balance-process.agi
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  287 Sep  1 08:21 CCsetvars.agi
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1.3K Sep  1 09:17 CCtest.agi
-rwxrwxrwx  1  555  555 1.3K Aug 31 16:59 CCtest.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1.8K Jan 17  2010 agi-test.agi
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  88K Jan 17  2010 eagi-sphinx-test
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 122K Jan 17  2010 eagi-test
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  15K Jan 17  2010 jukebox.agi
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  430 Sep  1 10:17 resp_example.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check that asterisk user ABLE run that script(including directory access)

After that, you have to debug for errors.

```
# stop asterisk
asterisk -r
core stop now
#start asterisk in console so you can see errors
asterisk -vvvgc
agi set debug on
```

ps Note, asterisk HAS internal func_CURL

Comment: As I said - "I have complex cURL with headers to send using -H which means I can not use Asterisk Curl" or I missed something?

Comment: Yes,asterisk can send headers in curl via curlopt

Comment: Yes and no, I need to send custom headers which is not allowed

Comment: CURLOPT: httpheader     - Add new custom http header (string)